# Difference in Use statement outside class / inside class

Tags: php, namespaces

I work with PHP for quite a long time now, and yesterday night I was thinking there is something I do not know the difference, maybe the difference is just code formatting or something similar, but i'm not sure, so here goes both cases and I would like to know the difference if there is one:

Case 1:

```
<?php

    namespace Foo\Bar;

    use Foo\Bar\Baz;

    class MyClass {
        public function __construct()
        {
             $instance = new Baz();
        }
    }

?>
```

Case 2:

```
<?php

    namespace Foo\Bar;

    class MyClass {
        public function __construct()
        {
             $instance = new \Foo\Bar\Baz();
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using **use** statement, we can bring one class from another namespace and you can reference it by some other name too. Something like this

```
use Foo\Bar\Baz as Baz2;
```

I don't think there is any performance issue, just a personal personal preference in my opinion.

Why I started using **use** statement?

I was recently working on project and when my namespaces got very long and it became a trouble to type whole path each time, whenever I need to instantiate that class.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, you can use your classes with an alias in order to make code more readable. It seems that everything is pointing out that the difference is only code readability.

Comment: Yes, I believe same and people use it to avoid typing the full hierarchy again and again as per my knowledge.

Comment: Well, makes sense, imagine a method that recieves 3 parameters, each one of them typed to a class from a different namespace, code would be unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, there is also the possibility that you might change to another implementation. For example, you start with `\Foo\Bar` but then later on notice that `\Baz\Bar` is a more performant implementation. In this case it would make sense to always use `use`, since then you'll only have to make the change in one place (provided the classes implement the same interface).

**Original answer:**

There is no functional difference (except in the number or characters required) in those cases.

I don't know if they differ performance wise, but I doubt that.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe if you write all the `use` outside the class, they would be always "imported", and if you use the FQN inside your methods, they would be imported upon evaluation, but im not sure since namespaces usually require autoloading.

Comment: @taxicala all classes need autoloading unless you explicitly `include` the class definition files. all the `use` statement does is create an alias to the fully qualified name